# how to draw shape using stars in C

Tags: c

I am trying to print starts like Image attached in nested for loop, but after writing code, I am getting the result like below

[image]

Following is code

```
int main() {
    int height = 5, y, z;
    for(int x=1; x<=height; x++)
    {
        for(y=1;y<=x;y++)
            printf("*");

        for(z=height-(2*x);z>0;z=z-2)
            printf(" ");
        for(y=1;y<=x;y++)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The result is following, but I need exact print like showing in the image.

```
*  *
** **
******
********
**********
```

Comment: Can you explain you logic behind the for loop: `for(z=height-(2*x);z>0;z=z-2)` when x is 1, you need to print out 8 spaces, yet you only print 2 (z=5-2*1=3, z=3-2=1 and then the end condition is met when z=1-2=-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just got the middle section wrong. Try this to print the spaces:

```
    for(z=0 ;z < height - x; ++z)
        printf("  "); // <- Notice there are 2 spaces being printed here.
```

Comment: Yes Its perfect

Comment: @AdeelMughal As a side note, you asked about C++, but you actually only use C. C++ is a very different language from C, but C programs can often be compiled as C++, because C is almost a subset of C++.